# Python - How to specify an optional argument for class based decorators?

Tags: python, decorator, memoization

How would I write a decorator like this.  I want to be able to specify the value for max_hits when I call the decorator (or optionally leave it out).

E.g., the desired use would be

```
@memoize(max_hits=7)
def a(val):
    print val
```

or

```
@memoize
def a(val):
    print val
```

(Using the first example gives an error about incorrect arguments.)

Decorator:

```
class memoize:
    """A decorator to cache previosly seen function inputs.

    usage:
        @memoize
        def some_func(..
    """
    def __init__(self, function, max_hits=None):
        self.max_hits = max_hits
        self.function = function
        self.memoized = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key = (args,tuple(kwargs.items()))
        try:
            return self.memoized[key]
        except KeyError:
            self.memoized[key] = self.function(*args,**kwargs)
        return self.memoized[key]
```

Comment: Why does everyone spell it memoize.

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#Etymology

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define a class with optional argument in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681038/define-a-class-with-optional-argument-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make `memoize` a *function* that takes an optional argument `max_hits` and returns a decorator (i.e. another callable object that will take the function as the first argument); in this case, you can use the following two syntaxes:

```
@memoize()
def func(x):
    [...]

@memoize(max_hits=7)
def func(x):
    [...]
```

So, probably something along the lines of:

```
def memoize(max_hits=None):
    """Returns a decorator to cache previosly seen function inputs.

    usage:
    @memoize()
    def some_func(..
    """
    class decorator:
        def __init__(self, function):
            self.max_hits = max_hits
            self.function = function
            self.memoized = {}

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            key = (args,tuple(kwargs.items()))
            try:
                return self.memoized[key]
            except KeyError:
                self.memoized[key] = self.function(*args,**kwargs)
            return self.memoized[key]

    return decorator
```

Note that `@memoize()` will work but your originally desired `@memoize` syntax won't; in the latter case, the function you are decorating with `@memoize` would be passed to `memoize` as the first argument (`max_hits`). If you want to treat this case, you can extend `memoize` as follows:

```
def memoize(max_hits=None):
    if callable(max_hits):
        # For sake of readability...
        func = max_hits
        decorator = memoize(max_hits=None)
        return decorator(func)
    [...original implementation follows here...]
```

Comment: So my decorator would return the class?

Comment: Yes; see my extended example above.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 3.2+, don't write it yourself, use `from functools import lru_cache` instead

If you want to support the no-parenthesis version, it is also better to use a sentinel value for the function argument rather than introspecting the "wrong" argument. That is:

```
class Memoized(object):
    # As per the memoize definition in the question

# Leave out the "*, " in 2.x, since keyword-only arguments are only in 3.x
from functools import partial
_sentinel = object()
def memoize(_f=_sentinel, *, max_hits=None):
    if _f is _sentinel:
        return partial(Memoized, max_hits=max_hits)
    return Memoized(_f, max_hits=max_hits)
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote something, it's polite to say *why*. The sentinel technique described here is the most robust way to allow a single function to serve as both a decorator factory (`@memoize(max_hits=7)` or `@memoize()`) and a decorator (`@memoize`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Great solution, works like a charm - I appreciate it.