# Define a class with optional argument in Python

Tags: python, class, arguments, default

```
class class1():
    def setdata(self,value1, value2):
    self.data = value1+value2
def display(self):
    print(self.data)
```

For the above code, when I use it. It will require exactly two arguments.

```
>>>a = class1()
>>>a.setdata('123','456')
```

But what if I want to set a `default value` for `value2`, for exmaple, its(`value2`) default value is `'000'`.

Next time when I use the class, I can either type

```
>>>a = class1()
>>>a.setdata('123')
```

`a.data` will be `'123000'`

Or I can type

```
>>>a = class1()
>>>a.setdata('123','654')
```

`a.data` will be `'123654'`

How to achieve this?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this please:

```
def setdata(self, value1, value2 = '000'):
   Your code here
```

Comment: pep8 recommends no spaces around equalsign.

Answer (score 6):

Try defining a [default argument](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values), like so.

```
class class1():
    def setdata(self,value1, value2='000'):
        ...
```

Comment: You should try to link to a newer version of the Python documentation. Python 1.x is a historical fossil these days.

Comment: For an explanation including the point where most people trip over: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/DefaultArgumentValues.html

Comment: @Li-aungYip Excellent point, I will update the link.  I was posting from my phone, so my requirements may have been lax.  :)

Answer (score 3):

```
class class1:    
    def setdata(self,value1, value2=456):
        self.data = value1+value2
    def display(self):
        print(self.data)
```

may be this solves your problem